# Angular Nested Controller in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use a nested controller in an ng-repeat so that the accordion panels on the page operate in different scopes (there may be a better way to do this).  The problem is that the code in the nested controller never gets executed.  I put a "debugger" stop point at the top and it never gets hit.

Here is my HTML:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/app/LWS/LWSCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/LWS/lwsService.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/Common/commonCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/Common/commonService.js"></script>

<div ng-app-="myModule" ng-controller="LWSCtrl">
<div cg-busy="waitopr"></div>
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Dashboard">
        <div ng-repeat="m in majors">
            <div ng-controller="commonCtrl">
                <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
                        <accordion-heading>
                            <div style="height:20px">
                                <span class="pull-left">{{m.MajorName}}</span><i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !status.open}"></i>
                            </div>
                        </accordion-heading>
...(shortened for brevity)
```

Here is the nested controller in its entirety:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('commonCtrl', function ($scope, commonService, $, $timeout, $filter, $interval, $window) {
debugger;
$scope.oneAtATime = true;
$scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: false,
    isFirstDisabled: false
};
getDashboard();
function getDashboard() {
    $scope.waitopr = commonService.getlwsdashboard()
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.dashboard = data;
        var arr = {};
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.dashboard.length; i < len; i++) {
            arr[$scope.dashboard[i]['CompanyID']] = $scope.dashboard[i];
        };
        $scope.majors = new Array();
        for (var key in arr) {
            $scope.majors.push(arr[key]);
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.majors, function (value, key) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dashboard.length; i++) {
                if (value.CompanyID == $scope.dashboard[i].CompanyID) {
                    $scope.majors[key].header = $scope.dashboard[i];
                };
            }
        })
        angular.forEach($scope.majors, function (value, key) {
            $scope.waitopr = commonService.getlegend(value.CompanyID)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.majors[key].Legend = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dashboard.length; i++) {
                    if (value.CompanyID == $scope.dashboard[i].CompanyID) {
                        $scope.majors[key].MajorName = $scope.dashboard[i].MajorName;
                    };
                }
            });//end success
        });//end forEach
        angular.forEach($scope.majors, function (value, key) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dashboard.length; i++) {
                if (value.CompanyID == $scope.dashboard[i].CompanyID) {
                    items.push($scope.dashboard[i]);
                };
            }
            $scope.majors[key].items = items;
            items = [];
        })


    });//end success
};
```

})

I don't understand why the nested controller code is not executing.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about the code for `LWSCtrl`? Your common controller will never be called if `majors` is an empty list. What happens if you just try to `ng-repeat` divs: can you prove that `majors` is populated?

Comment: That's probably it.  majors is populated by the nested controller.  I going to change some things around and see if that does it.  Thanks for the good eye!

Comment: Okay, well I tried calling the controller before the repeat so that it would not depend on majors, but it is still not getting hit.

Comment: Any errors logged in the console?

Comment: I get an injector error for commonCtrl.  It says unknown provider

Comment: You need to make sure that every service you're attempting to inject has been registered with your angular module: `$scope, commonService, $, $timeout, $filter, $interval, $window`

Comment: I thought this line did that angular.module('myModule').controller('commonCtrl', function ($scope, commonService, $, $timeout, $filter, $interval, $window) .  It is the way I create all of my controllers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106808/discussion-between-calvin-belden-and-rani-radcliff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is attached to an element within an `ng-repeat`. If the item you're repeating on is empty/undefined, your controller instance will never be invoked.

You must ensure that `majors` is populated and non-empty in the parent `$scope`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't want to mark this as the answer as this was not the solution to the original problem, but I typo I found myself.  The "real" answer, which you did provide, was that I needed to place the controller instance "before" the repeat because it was never being called because 'majors' was not populated.  This forum is supposed to help others and I'd rather mark the 'real' answer as it may help someone else.  Please post the correct answer, and I will gladly mark it.  Thanks for your time and assistance!